# What is this houseplant with glossy leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I planted this plant 4 years ago and it didnt even bloom. I'm not sure what it is.

[image]

Comment: If you scratch a leave or the bark does white sap come out?  Looks like ficus nitida

Comment: Rare to have indoor plants flower unless some serious lighting, ventilation and proper fertilization (with lower Nitrogen in proportion with Phosphorus and Potassium higher percentages, too much nitrogen, no flowers.  These leaves are quite thick, yes?

Comment: Did you purchase this plant?  My first impression was Camellia...japonica?  does that ring a bell?

Comment: I want to wager that this is Ficus benjamina, colloquially Weeping Fig. I saw the comment about Camellia, but I wonder if that would even survive indoors. Can you give us a shot of the stem. Ficus stems twist mostly. That could be a telling sign.

Comment: Seems it is some kind of Ficus tree thank you for your help Kevinsky.

Comment: Looks like my lavender plant

Comment: @Ljk2000 - if your 'lavender' plant looks like this, it's not a lavender...

Comment: No, I mean it looks similar to my lavender, did not mean it was... sorry fro the confusion

Comment: Ficus leaves are thinner.  These look pretty thick, just sayin'....oh and people do not purchase ficus plants for flowers.

Comment: Thank you guys if i scratch  a leave or the bark does white sap comes out so it it ficus nitida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but I agree it looks very like a Camelia, but the Ficus option is almost as good.

The tipping point for me is that Ficus has a smooth stem with joints, while I cannot see any joints here.

I will say it looks as if it's not happy and probably needs more light and perhaps better compost. Yellowing leaves suggest, to me, a lack of phosphates.

Answer (score -1):

looks like a rubber plant to me, and i don't believe it blooms.

Comment: It's not a rubber plant.